# How to invoke bunch of git commands from the remote location without going to that location

Tags: git, powershell, github, tfs

I want to invoke Git commands in my TFS post build script to push the artifact to AWS code commit. for that i need to invoke the git commands form the artifact location. how to do it, i can't do cd. Check the below commands and i created one powershell script which contains these commands and when i am invoking this script manually by going inside to folder. It's running fine. but if i invoke it from the TFS Build. It looks like its invoking this command somewhere else. Please help...

git init

git clone https://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/mv

git remote add origin https://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/mv

git checkout -b mvtest

git add mv.txt

git commit -m "First commit"

git push origin mvtest

Answer (score 1):

I would use Invoke-Command, something like the below should work assuming git is installed and integrated with PowerShell.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName RemoteComputer -ScriptBlock `
{set-location c:\;git init;git;git clone https://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/mv}
```

Use ';' to separate each command.

Comment: I did it with -C like git -C <Path> init. similar for all commands and its working. Anyways your suggestion is nice. I will try.